# How to get nested prompts result in yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am a javascript beginner and by following the writing your first generator tutorial and reading through other generators code I have managed to get this far with my first generator.

I have tried various ways to get this working and have failed miserably, I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction. I should probably point out I have used generator-generator v0.4.3

oops forgot to say the problem is getting the response from the flavour list.

```
askFor: function () {
    var done = this.async();

    var prompts = [{
      name: 'sitename',
      message: 'What would you like to name your app/site?',
      default: 'New Project'
    },{
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'features',
      message: 'Please choose additional features',
      choices:[{
        name: 'Modernizr',
        value: 'includeModernizr',
        checked: false
      },{
        name: 'Respond',
        value: 'includeRespond',
        checked: false
      }]
    },{
      type: 'list',
      name: 'flavour',
      message: 'Which type of css would you like to use?',
      choices: [{
        name: 'Sass',
        value: 'includeSass'
      },{
        name: 'Sass with Compass',
        value: 'includeCompass'
      },{
        name: 'Stylus',
        value: 'includeStylus'
      },{
        name: 'Standard css',
        value: 'includeCss'
      }]
      ,default: 1
    },{
      when: function (props) {
        return props.flavour.indexOf('includeSass') !== -1;
      },
      type: 'confirm',
      name: 'libsass',
      value: 'includeLibSass',
      message: 'Would you like to use libsass? Read about libsass at \n' + chalk.green('https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#nodesass'),
      default: false
    }];

    this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
      var features = props.features;

      function hasFeature (feat) {
        return features.indexOf(feat) !== -1;
      }

      this.sitename = props.sitename;

      this.includeModernizr = hasFeature('includeModernizr');
      this.includeRespond = hasFeature('includeRespond');

      //this is obviously the wrong way to do it
      this.includeSass = props.includeSass;

      this.includeLibSass = props.libsass;
      this.includeRubySass = !props.libsass;

      done();
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I seem to have solved this for myself. I have added another function hasFlavour the same as hasFeature but obiviously using flavour  and it is working. If this is the wrong way to do it please let me know.

Comment: where is your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the hasFeature function, you can use [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) from lodash. This is an easy way to extract choices.

```
this.includeModernizr = _.includes(props.features, 'includeModernizr');
```